# Trigonometry Word Problem Diagramming Pictorially

Tags: trigonometry

A footbridge is to be built across a small lake from a gazebo to a dock.  From a tree 100 yards from the gazebo the bearing is S 66° E.  From the tree to the dock the bearing is S 15° E.  The bearing from the Gazebo to the dock is S 33° W.  What is the length of the bridge?

How should I draw this on paper? It is for a review for a math quiz, but the wording is confusing. How do the bearings aid in solving the problem? And when the term bearing is used, is it clockwise or counter-clockwise?

Because there are angles and a distance given, an oblique triangle is formed, so I know that I should use the law of sines or cosines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bearing of S $x$ degrees E means that you start facing south and turn toward the east (which would be counterclockwise), $x$ degrees.  For S $x$ degrees W you start facing south and turn $x$ degrees toward the west (which would be clockwise).